# Layering HTML elements on each other

Tags: html, canvas

Alright, so, I need help on how to put HTML elements (specifically `<canvas>` and `<div>`) in a certain order and place, so, even, if, say, canvas 2's width or height get changed, it still stays in the same layer order, and to keep all of these elements in the same place on a HTML document (div 1 over canvas 2 over canvas 3 over div 4 over div 5 over div 6 etc.)

**EDIT: NEVERMIND**

Comment: http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php

Comment: EDIT: NEVERMIND :) good one